# Stop resizing view after show navigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uinavigationbar, tableview

I change     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO/YES animated:YES]; during my app life. Problem is then it begin hidden/unhidden - it resized view and tableView. How can I disable resizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disabling** or **editing** the **AUTOLAYOUT** in your Nib/Xib

*1. Open your interface
2. Click on the first tab on the inspector on the right;
3. Disable the auto layout.*

**OR if you need auto layout:**

*Cancel or edit the constraint that resize your tableview.*

I sugget to disable the auto layout in that screen if you don't know how it work and you don't need it.

Comment: self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
 ?

Comment: to remove the auto layout you have to follow my instruction. Do you have a nib?